# "Server DNS address could not be found" error after adding subdomain in cPanel

Tags: dns, subdomain, cpanel

I'm trying to create a subdomain through cPanel. After adding the subdomain and visiting it in the browser, I get a `This site can’t be reached - server DNS address could not be found`. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the DNS cache get updated. also check you have added a correct CNAME for the sub domain and DNS configuration for the sub domain

Plz let me know if you have made any changes while creating a sub domain to help you better way

Comment: "also check you have added a correct CNAME for the sub domain and DNS configuration for the sub domain" - could you elaborate on this? For example, if the domain was example.com and the new subdomain is support.example.com.

Comment: check the primary domain cname and sub domain cname and check same with primary domain and sub domain DNS server name for the both. it should be same or added sub domain dns is working. plz help me with the screenshot or reference

Comment: it will take almost 24 hours to 48 hours